# How do I temporarily sort a list alphabetically in reverse?

Tags: python, reverse, sortedlist

Like to use reverse sort in command its:
variable.sort(reverse=True)
but this is permanent.

The sorted command is only temporary such as:
print(sorted(variable))
so how do I make that one in reverse?

Comment: `sorted(variable, reverse=True)` ...? Did you forget that Python has a documentation? Look here: [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Answer (score 0):

Simple one :)

`sorted(your_list, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(variable,  reverse=True)
```

Use the keyword argument reverse inside the sorted function, and put it to True for it to be reversed

that should do exactly what you want